# Static methods of a class sharing a member(const) will be thread safe?

Tags: c#

```
public class Sample{

  private const ="constant string";

  public static object StaticMethod(args){

    var result= SomeOtherClass.StaticMethod(const,args);

    return result;

  }

}
```

will this code be thread safe?

Comment: It depends, what does SomeOtherClass.StaticMethod do?

Comment: It would help if you'd post *valid* code to start with.

Comment: @JonSkeet: In this case, it wouldn't really help :)

Comment: @SLaks: Well it would be a *starting* point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constants are thread safe by every means, As they are compiled into to their real values during compile time and their values never change during execution of program regardless of how many threads are accessing it :)

Once you will compile the code compiler will replace all references of const variable with constant's real value in your case it is "Constant String"
hence it will never change in its life time. until you change the value of constant variable it self and recompile the code.

I gave reference from Eric Lippert as he is a **principal developer on the C# compiler team.**

From [Eric's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/23/read-only-and-threadsafe-are-different.aspx)

> One of the much-touted benefits of immutable data structures is that
>   they are "threadsafe". **Since they cannot be written to, you'll never
>   run into a situation where a write operation is interrupted halfway by
>   a thread switch, causing another thread to read an inconsistent data
>   structure**. However, it is a fallacy to believe that just because a
>   data structure does not admit any way for you change its contents, its
>   implementation must be threadsafe!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add locking in order to ensure thread safety, in particular if `SomeOtherClass.StaticMethod` has side effects. Being static doesn't automatically make functions thread safe.

In general, if all you are doing is *reading*, then there is no thread safety issue (well, apart from resource contention).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unanswerable.

It completely depends on what the static method does.
For example, if the static method accesses UI, it will not be thread-safe even if called from inside a lock.